# Por que os meus vetores não armazenam as informações dos meus textbox ? Já tentei de tudo

Tags: vba, excel-vba

```
Sub Email()
Dim z, i, count As Integer
Dim r(100000), s(100000), t(100000), u(100000), v(100000), w(100000) As String
Dim a As String
a = txtDataDOU.Value
count = 0
For i = 1 To z
    If Cells(i, 4).Value = a Then
    r(i) = txtDataDespacho
    s(i) = txtNumeroDespacho.Value
    t(i) = txtDataDOU.Value
    u(i) = txtOrdem.Value
    v(i) = txtLink.Value
    w(i) = txtResumo.Value
    count = count + 1
    End If
Next
txtDataDespacho.Value = ""
txtNumeroDespacho.Value = ""
txtDataDOU.Value = ""
txtOrdem.Value = ""
txtLink.Value = ""
txtResumo.Value = ""
Dim objeto_outlook As Outlook.Application
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Objeto para Outlook
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) 'Objeto para email dentro do Outlook
For i = 1 To count + 1
With OutMail
.display
.to = Cells(14, 1).Value
.Subject = "Atos do dia " & a
.Body = "Daespacho N° " & r(count) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & w(i) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " Link: " & v(i)
End With
Next
MsgBox "E-mail enviado com sucesso !!!", vbInformation, "Informação"
End Sub
```

Comment: Duas perguntas: você setou o valor de Z? Sem isso, provavelmente será 0 e o loop não vai iterar vez nenhuma.

Comment: 2. Essa ```Sub``` chamada Email está em que módulo? Se estiver no módulo do mesmo form que contém as ```Textbox``` todo bem, mas se estiver num módulo diferente, você tem um problema de escopo. Nesse caso, pra referenciar o conteúdo das caixas de texto será necessário setar uma variável com o objeto ```Form``` e usar ```minhaVariavel.txtDataDespacho.Value```.

Comment: Obrigado, eu já resolvi o meu problema.